# Connected scheme of dimension $0$ which admits a monomorphism to an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be a connected scheme of dimension $0$ (not necessarily Noetherian). If there exists an affine scheme $Y$ such that there exists a monomorphism (in the category of schemes) $X \to Y$, then is $X$ affine ?

If this is not true in general, what if we also assume $Y$ is Noetherian ?

Comment: Where are these strange questions coming from? You've asked like 100 questions about zero dimensional schemes?

Comment: @AlexYoucis but there is nothing wrong with asking questions, right? Why label them "strange"?

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat Because they are strange. That doesn't mean 'bad' or 'wrong', just strange. If the OP can contextualize the problem it might be helpful to help them get at what they are ultimately interested in. If the questions they've asked here is what they're ultimately interested in, that's fine. But with such a thematic series of questions I would guess this is not the case.

Comment: I see. But then it should be probably said they are strange from your perspective (as they are from mine). Otherwise I agree.